# Routing for root gives "can't convert String into Hash"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm trying to route '/' to my elections controller and new action:

```
Awesomevote::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'election#new'
  resources :elections, :path => "vote"
```

This is producting an error:

```
can't convert String into Hash
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although both should work based on the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Try changing:

```
root 'election#new'
```

to:

```
root to: 'elections#new' # elections (pluralized) for controller name.
```

**Update:**

So `root 'elections#new'` works as specified in the linked doc in rails 4.0 but not in Rails 3.2'.  Rails 3.2 requires the `to:` option.

Comment: Works.  I also needed to pluralize "election".  Thanks.

Comment: Yes 'elections' for controller!  Updated answer.